# Creating a file in Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have an application which saves the user uploaded file to disk does some processing and creates a new file on the disk with the processed data and returns to the user.

I am migrating this application to kubernetes and when i deploy the application it is erroring out when trying to save file to local disk.

any suggestion?

Comment: "it is erroring out" -- What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Save your file to an [emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) volume for this kind of temporary storage.

See the configuration [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir-configuration-example) in the documentation, that use this kind of volume for "cache":

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /cache
      name: cache-volume
  volumes:
  - name: cache-volume
    emptyDir: {}
```